# How could be deprecated Net::SSH->poll avoided

Tags: perl, libssh2, perlnetssh

[Net::SSH2->poll](https://metacpan.org/pod/Net::SSH2#poll-timeout-arrayref-of-hashes) doc:

> Deprecated: the poll functionality in libssh2 is deprecated and its usage disregarded. Session methods "sock" and "block_directions" can be used instead to integrate Net::SSH2 inside an external event loop.

Can someone provide an example how "sock" and "block_directions" could be used instead of deprecated poll function?